# Is there any function that is used to decrease the date by year when the key has null value

Tags: mule4

FOllowing is the input that i have
[{
"date": " "
},
{
"date": "2022-01-21"
},{
"date": " "
},{
"date": " "
},{
"date": " "
}]
And the required output is as follows

[
{
"Date": "2022-01-21"
},
{
"Date": "2021-01-21"
},
{
"Date": "2020-01-21"
},
{
"Date": "2019-01-21"
},
{
"Date": "2018-01-21"
}
]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by decreasing the date when there is a null value exactly? Decreased with respect to what initial value? In your example the second element of the array has a value ("2022-01-21") and it is replaced by something else.

Answer (score 1):

It should be obvious that there is no buil-in function in DataWeave to achieve this result. You can create a custom function for it. For example using a recursive function we can get the expected output from your input:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun decDates(a, nextDate)=
    [{date: nextDate}]
     ++         
    if (sizeOf(a) > 1) decDates(dw::core::Arrays::drop(a, 1), nextDate - |P1Y|) else []
---
decDates(payload, |2022-03-21|)
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2022-03-21"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-03-21"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-03-21"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-03-21"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-03-21"
  }
]
```